# How to map keys to a different key

Tags: vim

I have just started learning VIM using gvim. When I am in the insert mode, and after I have copied stuff ,I usually use CTRL+R + Shift * key combination to paste the stuff in. I would like to map those keys to CTRL+V .
Can you please let me know what I should be doing in my vimrc to achieve my desired goal?
I am on a Windows OS.

Thanks

Comment: 0 Experience with vim on windows. But can you try `inoremap <c-v> <c-r>*`?  And on my linux box, the insert mode `Ctrl-v` is very important, it can let me input  next non-digit literally..... It is very handy to input special keys.

Comment: @kent - the key combination that you provided , does it take into account Shift + * keypress keystrokes as well ? Sorry for being so lame...

Comment: on my keyboard, `*` is `shift-8`, what is `shift-*`?? how do you press it?

Comment: @kent - sorry about that- you are right .. let me give that a go !!!

Comment: @kent - that works.. can you please post it as an answer for me to mark it as the correct answer , please? - thanks

Comment: okay, make it as ansewr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 0 Experience with vim on windows. But you can try `inoremap <c-v> <c-r>*`

And on my linux box, the insert mode Ctrl-v is very important, it can let me input next non-digit literally. It is very handy to input special keys. So if it is same to you, consider to use other keys.

Comment: `<c-v>` and `<c-q>` are the same however `<c-q>` does not work well on all terminals with flow control enabled, but it should work on windows. See `:h i_CTRL-Q`. To disable flow control do: `stty -ixon`

Answer (score 1):

The key combination

:map < c-v > P

should set the paste shortcut to Ctrl+V.

There is a tutorial for creating VIM keymaps [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)).

You can also try the 3rd chapter of the free book "[Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/03.html)". It gives a very good example of mapping "dd" to "-". I would actually visit this link first and maybe afterwards take the tutorial above.

Comment: yep, i have been there. that link was my first port of call. Unfortunately, call me lame, but i could not make much of what was said . Sorry!